# YouCompleteMe plugin of VIM not working with NLTK

Tags: python, vim

I have recently installed the YouCompleteMe plugin for vim through Vundle. It works really well for Python. Problem starts when I import the third party library nltk. For example if I do the following import:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
```

And then type something like this:

```
print brown.
```

I get the following suggestions:

[image: YCM]

However in idle as well as bpython I get the correct suggestions:

[image: IDLE]
[image: BP]

How can I make it work in YouCompleteMe?